# sqlite3: create unique index error

Tags: sqlite

I have an IPCC climatic time series for BRASIL with 67 million of records inside a table named weather_grid where idgrid and day are the dimensions.

If I did:

```
select idgrid,day from weather_grid group by idgrid,day having count(*) > 1;
```

I have no rows...

instead if I did:

```
create unique index weather_grid_idx01 on weather_grid(idgrid,day);
```

I receive the message: "Error: indexed columns are not unique"

Is a bug ?

sqlite3: 3.7.17
kernel:  3.10.0-327.18.2.el7
linux: RedHat 7.3 (Maipo)

Comment: Show the table definition. Try a newer `sqlite3` tool.

Comment: CREATE TABLE weather_grid(idgrid text not null,day text not null,temperature_max real,temperature_min real,temperature_avg real,windspeed real,precipitation real,radiation real,humidity real);